# Как сделать запрос на С# с выбором сервиса **NB Provisioning Web Service**

Tags: c#

Как на C# реализовать запрос с выбором нужного сервиса **NB Provisioning Web Service**?

Захожу по адресу

```
http://10.115.1.3/openmn/test
```

Затем ввожу логин/пароль:  admin/admin, происходит авторизация. Открывается HTML страница. Вот её код

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OpenMN Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method=post>
<p>Select service
    <select name="service">
         <option value="OpenMnsGenericWebService">OpenMnsGeneric Web Service
         <option value="BBProvisioningWebService">BB Provisioning Web Service
         <option value="NBAssuranceWebService">NB Assurance Web Service
         <option value="NBProvisioningWebService">NB Provisioning Web Service
         <option value="TestWebService">Test Web Service
    </select>
</p>
Request:<BR>
<textarea name="request" cols=95 rows=12></textarea>
<P><input type=submit value="OK">
</form>
<BR><BR> Response:<BR>
<textarea name="response" cols=95 rows=12>
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Далее я выбираю сервис --- **NB Provisioning Web Service**. Затем  в textarea **Request** ввожу запрос

```
searchSubscribersRequest

subscriber areaCode="4422" dn="675636"

searchSubscribersRequest
```

Нажимаю кнопку OK, и в  в textarea Response
получаю ответ

```
searchSubscribersResponse

  subscriber areaCode="4422" dn="675636" equipped="yes" node="20009"

searchSubscribersResponse
```

На Си# получается только авторизоваться и получить HTML код странички. Как же сделать запрос с  выбором нужного сервиса?

```
private void SubmitData()
{

    try {
        string user = textBox1.Text;
        string pass = textBox2.Text;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string auth = "admin:admin";
        string u = "admin";
        string p = "admin";

        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(auth);

     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://10.115.1.3/openmn/test");

    request.Credentials= new NetworkCredential(u,p);

        request.Method = "POST";
        //POST /openmn/nb/NBProvisioningWebService HTTP/1.1
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate");
        request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
  //      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "getSubscriberRequest");
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
   //     request.Headers.Add("HOST", "10.115.1.3");

        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset:utf-8;");

 //   request.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1");
  //      request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(stream);

        this.output_txt.Text = rd.ReadToEnd();
        rd.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error : "  + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Как же сделать запрос на С#  с выбором сервиса **NB Provisioning Web Service**?